# Help with Shading for a pencil model

Tags: modeling, shaders

I'm currently working on a tutorial for modeling and shading a pencil, and I'm trying to make the shading good enough to create those distinct markings made on it by sharpening it.

Here's where I am in the tutorial...
https://youtu.be/OaB92KsvOtM?t=255
Here are some images I'm talking about...

[image: reference example 1]

[image: reference example 2]

And here is a link to the downloadable file of the project I'm working on...

[image: screenshot from blend file]

[image]

Updated model:

[image: screenshot 2]

[image]

Comment: Yes, the updated model looks much better :-)

Answer (score 1):

Compared to the tutorial your shader nodes differ slightly. That's the reason why it looks different. But it's easy to fix.

**Shader adjustments**

- increase the *Scale* of the *Voronoi Texture* to `50`
- remove the 3 duplicated *Color Ramp* nodes on the first one. There are a bunch of them stacked on top of each other.
- set the *Fac* of the *MixRGB (Multiply)* node to `1` and adjust the color a little bit, less saturated (S) and higher brightness (V), something like `EEC176` (HEX).
- make the first color of the first *Color Ramp* a grey value like `E5E5E5`.
- increase the first slider of the second *Color Ramp* to the middle as shown a bit later in the video.

**Mesh adjustments**

Switch to *Edit* mode, select everything and remove the **duplicated vertices** with <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*. Repeat this for the other pencil.

**Optional adjustments**

Scale the pencils down to real-world size and apply the *Scale* in *Object* mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale*. This way you can easily append the pencils to other scenes and you don't run into issues with the lighting.

You also can add a *Bevel* modifier, to make the end of the pencil look more natural and not that sharp-edged.

In Eevee render settings, turn on *Ambient Occlusion* and *Screen Space Reflection*. Last but not least, set up an HDRI in the world shader settings like [Cayley Interior](https://polyhaven.com/a/cayley_interior) and the pencils will look like this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I don't see these extra color ramps anywhere for the shader. What do I do?

Comment: Which extra color ramps do you mean? There are just two color ramp nodes as shown on the screenshots and the video...

Comment: What is the real world size for a pencil when thinking in Blender?

Comment: Does this look like an improvement? [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=aL7gyBlY" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/aL7gyBlY/)

Comment: Does this look like an improvement? What do I do next? [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=aL7gyBlY" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/aL7gyBlY/)

Comment: Blender's measurement unit is 'meter' by default. You can check the dimensions of an object in the side panel ("N-panel", key N to open it). Your pencil is about 8 meters tall. A common pencil is about 16-18 cm long and 7-8 mm thick. So you need to scale it down by a factor of 0.021. Size comparison => https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl7Lh.jpg -- Yes, it looks like an improvement!

Comment: Do you think the marks on the pencil look good, or does it need to be improved a bit more?

Comment: Should I be worried if the model I'm working on doesn't look EXACTLY like the one in the tutorial?

Comment: Shouldn't the exposed parts of the wood have lines going down them?

Comment: It looks fine to me. But it depends on what are you going for. If you want to have it super-realistic in a closeup render then you might want to tweak it a bit more. If you want to use it for animation (holding it in the hand, writing a letter, or so) it's totally fine. You don't be worried if it doesn't look exactly like in the tutorial. It's your pencil. It's fine when you like it ;-) The difference is the scale of 0.1 by the way. And for critique is better to ask here: https://blenderartists.org/c/artwork/focused-critiques/ since this here is question and answer site, not a forum.